# How to get cross validation accuracy from $best.model in tune.svm (e1071)?

Tags: r, svm

I am able to get the cv accuracy of the model from svm without tuning, as of following.

```
model=svm(formula,data,kernel=kernel,gamma=gamma,degree=degree,coef0=coef0,cost=cost,cross=10)
model$tot.accuracy
```

However, I am not able to get the cv accuracy of the model from svm when I used tune.svm.

```
data(iris)
obj <- tune.svm(Species~., data = iris, cost = 1:2, gamma = 1:2, kernel = "radial") 
obj$best.model
```

Any idea on how to get the accuracy from $best.model?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Accuracy can be obtained by

```
obj$best.performance
```

Comment: this value refers to the minimum error of all the tuning combinations right? can you elaborate more on this value? thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes. For classification, performance measures the classification error; for regression, performance measures the mean squared error. `obj$best.performance` gives you the minimum error achieved by using the optimal combination of hyperparameters in the grid-search, i.e., cost from 1 to 2 and gamma from 1 to 2. You can also see all the performance measures using `obj$performances`. Hope my answer helps.